# Bug with .animate()'s callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make some div to animate, then in the callback, call another function. Nothing hard. Here's the code:

```
function transfertMenu(){
    var chosenOption = this.firstChild.firstChild.id;
        $('#leftMenucontent').animate({
            left:'0px'
        }, 500, constructMenu());
    $('#leftMenucontent > ul > li').remove();
    chooseMenu(chosenOption);
}
```

and tried

```
function transfertMenu(){
    var chosenOption = this.firstChild.firstChild.id;
        $('#leftMenucontent').animate({
            left:'0px'
        }, 500, function() {
        constructMenu();
    });
    $('#leftMenucontent > ul > li').remove();
    chooseMenu(chosenOption);
}
```

The problem is that when I put an alert() in the callback (constructMenu) it works perfectly, the animation finishes, then the alerts pops up. When I enter a function, it starts at the beginning, before the animation completes. Is it a bug, or i'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should remove `()` from callback function because otherwise it gets called  immediately:

```
 $('#leftMenucontent').animate({
    left:'0px'
 }, 500, constructMenu());
------problem --------^
```

Should be:

```
 $('#leftMenucontent').animate({
    left:'0px'
 }, 500, constructMenu);
```

So specify your callback function as `constructMenu` instead of `constructMenu()`

Comment: You're right! Thx. But what if I want to pass parameters? Can I add the ()?